# Como faço esta função exibir a data em PT BR

Tags: php, data

Como faço para esta função abaixo exibir a data no padrão brasileiro?
Tentei utilizar a função `_i18n`, mas não sei usar-la corretamente.

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'supermag_date_display' ) ) :
    function supermag_date_display( $format = 'l, F j, Y') {
        echo $time = current_time( $format, $gmt = 1 );
    }
endif;
```

**Obs:** O servidor utilizado no site é dos USA.

Obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer, mas eu acho que sei o que pode ser... defina seu `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo')`

Comment: Você quis dizer a data nesse formato `$format = 'd/m/Y H:i:s'` mostrará `11/06/2016 13:39:38` ou o `date_default_timezone_set` do @ViníciusLima? Tente deixar a sua pergunta mais clara .